# Maximum limit on number of variable in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Since pine script is not a object oriented language, is there a maximum limit to the number of variable which could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, maximum `1000`, in the global scope as mentioned [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-initialize-a-series-on-specific-dates-using-external-data).